# MySQL query for two way relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

For a social web application I needed to create a MySQL table in following way,

```
id | user_id | friend_id
------------------------
 0 |    5    |   6
 1 |    6    |   5
```

user 5 and another user 6 are now friends. How can I get a list of friends for a particular user. Could somebody point me in to the right direction please?

Comment: `SELECT` the friend id `WHERE` the user id equals to something ?

Comment: Problem is that something is what?

Comment: @shan @iamsleepy means `SELECT friend_id FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 5`

Comment: Is that the complete table,or do you have more columns?>

Comment: @Mihai: thats all I got, Thats the problem I'm facing. I wrote other codes, except code to get friends list. So I cannot change the table structure now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f1.user_id, f2.user_id as 'Friend'
    FROM friends f1 left join friends f2
   on f1.user_id = f2.friend_id
```

For more information please refer to this post [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I get this list for a particular userid?

Comment: Add a where condition to the same query - 'where f1.user_id = 5'

Answer (score 1):

If you store friend_ids for all users, you can try this:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM TableName WHERE user_id=@userID
```

Pass the parameter @userID from the program.

Example:

```
SELECT friend_id FROM TableName WHERE user_id=5
```

**EDIT**

For both fields:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN friend_id=5 THEN user_id 
            WHEN user_id=5 THEN friend_id 
            END AS Friend
 FROM TableName
```

Comment: The both rows is a must to make a comeplete friendship. There may be one. But I need the both rows are met by the query.

Comment: yeah!!! I was looking for something like that. Thanks for enlightening me @Raging Bull

Answer (score 0):

`@userid` should have the same datatype as in table or you need to convert it to the same

```
select friend_id where user_id=@userid
```